# solve the following system of linear equation by substitution by first isolating $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

**Here's what I was given:**

$x$ + $y$ = 9

-10$x$ + 6$y$ = 6

Firstly, in order to isolate $x$, I changed the first line so that $y$ would equal the equation and I got:

$x$ - 9 = -$y$

In the second equation, I replaced $y$ with $x$ - 9 = -$y$ in order to solve for $x$:

-10$x$ + 6($x$-9) = 6

$x$ = -15

I solved for $y$ by replacing my newfound $x$ value into the equation:

-10(-15) + 6$y$ = 6

$y$ = -24

Final answer: (-15, -24)

(the right answer in the textbook: (3, 6)

**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Check whether you substituted the correct value of $y$ in the second equation. $y = 9-x$ not $x-9$.

Comment: how should i get that? :)

Comment: @mathisn'tmyforte You wrote $x-9=-y$, which means that $9-x=y$!

Comment: @mathisn'tmyforte you didn't pay attention to the sign of y, in the evaluated part. Had you changed the sign ( and the other part of the equation to match) you would get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> In the second equation, I replaced $y$ with $x - 9 = -y$ in order to solve for $x$:

This is where you made your error.  You cannot replace $y$ with $-y$ since $y \neq -y$ unless $y = 0$.

Let's see how we can fix your error.  We are given
\begin{align*}
x + y & = 9 \tag{1}\\
-10x + 6y & = 6 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
If we subtract $x$ from both sides of equation 1, we obtain 
$$y = 9 - x$$
Substituting $9 - x$ for $y$ in equation 2 yields 
\begin{align*}
-10x + 6(9 - x) & = 6 && \text{substitute $9 - x$ for $y$}\\
-10x + 54 - 6x & = 6 && \text{distribute}\\
-16x + 54 & = 6 && \text{combine like terms}\\
-16x & = -48 && \text{subtract $54$ from each side of the equation}\\
x & = 3 && \text{divide both sides of the equation by $-16$}
\end{align*}
Substituting $3$ for $x$ in the equation $y = 9 - x$ yields $y = 9 - 3 = 6$.  Hence, the solution is $(3, 6)$.